# Dynamic Workbook Name changes and cell references - Is it possible?

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, excel-formula

my question is a pre-code question, as I would like to verify if and which is the best option to go about this - either formula, VBA or not possible.

I have a main workbook with an array of codes inside cells in sheet 1 - all in the format HXXX-XXX-XXX where X is numbers ranging from 0-9. Each code has an associated revision number as shown in the attached picture.

[image]

The workbook itself is named in the format: 'HXXX-XXX-XXX-YY Example Title' where YY can be any number starting from 0 to infinity (in theory). Only YY is subject to updates in the title. If changes are made in this workbook, then a new version is saved, with the YY changing in the title to the next consecutive number - Nothing else changes.

From this main workbook there are a large number of other workbooks (around 50) which share the same codes and revisions. My goal is to link all these workbooks up so that I only have to update a core main workbook and the rest of the codes (HXXX-XXX-XXX) revisions in all the other linked workbooks update accordingly.

The problem is that the other linked workbooks have a dynamic name in the format: 'HXXX-XXX-XXX-YY Example Title 2' where YY can be any number starting from 0 to infinity. YY gets updated to the next consecutive number if a change is made inside the document and this document is then saved as a separate document using Save As. NOTE: not all workbooks will get updated at the same time, as it all depends on which codes and therefore revisions are changing.

My question is firstly, is this possible with current excel functions to update links with ever-changing workbook links, which are saved as different files each time in the same folder?

Secondly, I have read about the INDIRECT function, but it is limited only to having the required workbooks opened at the same time as the updates to the main workbook, hence I am unsure that Formulas will work (I will be linking 50 workbooks to the main workbook) - From this I am gauging that VBA may be the best option, but I would like to double check this is possible before I begin attempting the code.

Of course the use of Formulas in the sheets would be much better, but because the file names are dynamic, and since the updated workbooks are saved as different files each time changes are made to it, I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: Hi @DecimalTurn thanks for getting in touch! The idea is that +/- 50 workbooks will be reading from the core workbook, as the +/- 50 worksbooks have lots of duplicates that need to be manually updated. My only concern is that when the core document is updated its YY value will be updated to the next consecutive number, and Saved As a separate document - so will I lose the links in this case if I use forumlas? Also I would be looking to have the updates carried out in the background and wouldnt want to be opening up every document for the INDIRECT formulas to work?

Comment: I guess my question extends to the possibility of using VBA to take any changes made to the HXXX-XXX-XXX revision numbers in the core workbook, and then search the other most up to date version of +/- 50 workbooks to see if the same changes need to be made, and apply those changes. If changes are made, then I would need to save the updated +/-50 workbooks as a new version with the YY value in the title name going to the next consecutive number - I hope this makes sense. I am not sure that is possible, but it would save so much manual work and duplication.

Comment: Does a previous question titled "Reference name-changing workbook in VBA" help with this? (apologies I don't know how to link to another question on this) Unfortunately my VBA knowledge does not extend to file names and parsing file names so any help on this side would be greatly appreciated. -

Comment: From what I understand, there are 3 workbooks in question when a change is made. The workbook that stores all HXXX and revision values and nothing else, the main HXXX workbook that is up-to-date and has no YY value, and the latest HXXX-YY workbook that is the most recent updated revision workbook. So what you want is that if the main HXXX is updated, you want the revision count in the versions workbook to increment and for a new workbook HXXX-YY to be saved to reflect the most recent revision version. Am I correct in my interpretation of your question? I believe it can be done using VBA.

Comment: Hi Lorne, there are only 2 workbooks involved. The main workbook will contain all HXXX codes and revisions contained in all +/- 50 workbooks ( a lot of which are heavily duplicated). Every workbook including the main workbook has a YY value which will be updated each time changes are made and saved as a new version. Yes precisely, the revisions are my only focus, so if a HXXX revision number goes up in the main workbook, that I want this to happen to all other workbooks which have the same HXXX code. I hope this makes sense. My only concern is the save as function.

Comment: Let's say you are working on H001-001-002-2 and make some changes in this workbook. You then simply save this workbook (by clicking the save button or ctrl+s) and instead this workbook is automatically saved as H001-001-002-3 and the previous workbook is retained as is, and the workbook of all records of up-to-date workbooks is incremented by 1. Would this deliver the desired outcome? You can do this by listening to Workbook.BeforeSave events and respond with Workbook.SaveAs. You would need to listen for the BeforeSave event from the PERSONAL workbook, a little complicated. Would this help?

Comment: This is hard to explain without seeing documents, so I apologise for how long winded it is and for taking the time to understand it so thank you @Lorne! Yes this is what I am looking for. It is an update of the main workbook to a revision number for a particular HXXX-XXX-XXX code. I would then want the macro to search all other documents and if it finds the same HXXX-XXX-XXX code that it makes the same update to the revision number - all referencing from the core workbook. Then save as you have just suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you need to differentiate between 3 things.

**Using only Excel Formulas.**
The problem with this is that formulas crossing workbooks have the big disadvantage, that you need to have the source-workbook open, otherwise manny formulas will not work correctly or update. You also have the disadvantage that saving the file needs still to be done automatically. The advantage is that you do not need VBA macros.

**Using Power Query**
With Power Query youmight be able to solve the problems with the dynamic names.You can even read a whole folder of files, combine them and do transformations without the need to open the files manually. But you still need to save new files manually and the files will only update once they are opened.

**Using VBA**
You can prettymuch do everything you asked in your problem description but VBA has its own disadvantages. Firstly the file-format ".xlsm" is not allowed by the IT department everywhere. Also to work, every user using the files needs to activate macros, otherwise the macros won't get executed. Therefore I think a VBA solution is better fitted if you only have a small circle of users or if you can execute the macros on your own (e.g. if the main workbook was updated, you need to execute a macro which opens, modifies and saves all affected files). After that you colleagues do not need VBA themself.

*Possible solution:*
To avoid VBA you could try to create a Power Query in each "other workbook". The query will read all filenames in the folder where the main workbook is located. Now you sort and filter for the workbook with the newest/highest ID/Titel automatically and load the result as an seperate Excel sheet (all that is possible with power query and without VBA).
Now you can use the "indirect" formula to use the ID/Titel to link to the newest main workbook. As mentioned above this will require that the main workbook is opened. Otherwise the indirect formula will not update the values. If that is out of the question, you probably need to go with VBA.

Comment: And then there is python that can do everything. In this instance sky is not the limit, only one's skill is.

Comment: @ Danny Papadopulos you are right, but I expected that the solution has to involve Excel because @vbAmateur mentioned "either formula, VBA or not possible". But I wanted to point out, that Power Query which is automatically included in Excel 2016 and later could also be an option.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for getting in touch! At present I am looking for just focusing on excel, but python is an exciting option for the future, and a very powerful one! I like the sound of power query, and to be honest had not heard of it before this forum - so will have a look into that. Any advice on power query would be great if you ever have the time to share! I accepted your answer as it covered all basis so thanks for that! One last question, can you link power query up with a macro? That sounds like I could then save the documents with a macro after power query has done the updates I need!

Comment: Yes, you can totally do that with Vba. There are a few youtube videos covering a tutorial. Also udemy is a good startingpoint for nearly everything. You can find there hands on courses for excel, vba, power query or python. They are often on sale for 10 bucks per course. Just be careful to only take ones which have a decent rating.